# How to fix " pyodbc.Error: No driver name specified;" when using Python and Mssql server in docker container

Tags: python, sql-server, docker-compose, pyodbc

I am setting up docker container for my application, where I want to connect python code with Microsoft sql server.

Following is the setup and python code

```
odbcinst.ini
[FreeTDS]Description=FreeTDS unixODBC Driver Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64- 
linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so

Python
import pyodbc
server = '127.0.0.1'
db = 'bd1'
drivers = [item for item in pyodbc.drivers()]
driver = drivers[-1]
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + server + '/' + db + "?" + 
driver)
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={driver};SERVER=' + server + 
';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + db + ';UID=SA;PWD=MyPass123!')


Docker-compose.yml

version: '3'
services:
  pyth:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "MyPass123!"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
```

This is the error I am getting

```
"No driver name specified; "
pyth_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
pyth_1  |   File "testing_sql.py", line 15, in <module>
pyth_1  |     conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={driver};SERVER=' + server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + db + ';UID=SA;PWD=MyPass123!')
pyth_1  | pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'driver' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I think the problem is in the below line-

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={driver};SERVER=' + server + 
';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + db + ';UID=SA;PWD=MyPass123!')
```

Here the driver is not being used as a variable. So If you are using python3 then doing this should resolve your issue.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER=' + server + 
';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + db + ';UID=SA;PWD=MyPass123!')
```